# How to lifetime annotate From trait in rust when indexing vector

Tags: rust, struct, traits, lifetime

I'd like to use the From trait to extract values from a json input into my struct `CreateUser`. If I extract the full `etc` vector as `etc: Vec<String>` it works fine, but I only need the second field of `etc` which is `2` in the CreateUser struct. Following the compiler hints I also couldn't get it to work.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=563063a1cc9a722e7f41aa17b74c8f57

The code:

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

static INPUT: &str = r#"{
    "email" : "",
    "password" : "",
    "etc" : ["1", "2"]
}"#;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct InputUser {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    etc: Vec<String>,
}

struct CreateUser<'a> { 
    email: String,
    password: String,
    only_second_field_in_etc_vector: &'a str,
}

impl From<InputUser> for CreateUser {
    fn from(i: InputUser) -> CreateUser {
        CreateUser {
            email: i.email,
            password: i.password,
            // Problem here
            only_second_field_in_etc_vector: &i.etc[1],
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input: InputUser = serde_json::from_str(INPUT).unwrap();
    let create_user = CreateUser::from(input);
}
```

Comment: Use an owned `String` instead of a `&str`: `only_second_field_in_etc_vector: i.etc[1],` or `only_second_field_in_etc_vector: i.etc[1].clone(),`

Comment: `i.etc[i]` will not work, you need to use `drain()` or `take()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `From` trait will drop the `input` you cannot reference the field by reference, you will have to take the whole `String` value. The following code will take the second value into the given field.

```rust
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;

static INPUT: &str = r#"{
    "email" : "",
    "password" : "",
    "etc" : ["1", "2"]
}"#;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct InputUser {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    etc: Vec<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct CreateUser {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    only_second_field_in_etc_vector: String,
}

impl From<InputUser> for CreateUser {
    fn from(i: InputUser) -> CreateUser {
        CreateUser {
            email: i.email,
            password: i.password,
            // Problem here
            only_second_field_in_etc_vector: i.etc.into_iter().skip(1).next().unwrap(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input: InputUser = serde_json::from_str(INPUT).unwrap();
    eprintln!("{:?}", CreateUser::from(input));
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f08a8613bfadb15001ae5d03b5f262a1